# Click on multiple checkboxes at the same time with selenese (selenium)

Tags: selenium

Given the html below, I want to click, with a selenese (selenium xml), all cheboxes which name attribute is "y".

With or whitout (if possible) flow control js.

Code example:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <form action="">
   <input type="checkbox" name="x" value="v1">v1<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="x" value="v2">V2<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="x" value="v3">v3<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="y" value="v4">v4<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="y" value="v5">v5<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="y" value="v6">v6<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="z" value="v7">v7<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="z" value="v8">v8<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="z" value="v9">v9<br>
  </form> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: why would you want to do that? with selenium we imitate what normally a user would do,and i'm sure no one will try to click on all the checkboxes at the same time...

Comment: Not all but some of them. Completely logic.